# FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, prelaunch

I am not using any Firebase or Youtube code/libraries in my project. Yet recently, in Android Pre-Release Reports I am seeing crashes with this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 26820
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
    at aewu.b(PG:1)
    at duc.a(PG:230)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at aevw.b(PG:1)
    at dud.al(PG:5)
    at dud.aw(PG:4)
    at dud.bg(PG:8)
    at duc.a(PG:232)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at afke.a(PG:1)
    at aeri.b(PG:1)
    at dud.fv(PG:4)
    at duc.c(PG:269)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at amfk.a(PG:1)
    at eiu.K(PG:5)
    at dud.fV(PG:7)
    at duc.d(PG:334)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
    at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at usj.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Here's another log with more detail, but different problems:

```
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 16751
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
    
    [redacted]

    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
    at avgp.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at usj.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    
    [redacted]

    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1680)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
Caused by: dkp: libelements.so
    at dks.c(PG:52)
    ...
```

Any ideas please?

I have no idea what `dkp: libelements.so`" is. Googling shows no results.

I uploaded a version to Google Play with `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` both set to `false`, yet the Firebase/Youtube errors in Pre-Launch Reports are still obfuscated. And it only affects two devices: Nokia 1 and Huawei P8 青春版.

When I uploaded the unobfuscated file to Google Play, I was warned that my app contained obfuscated code and that I should upload a map file. I have no idea how the Firebase/Youtube code is in my binary, and looking through my commits there have been no updates to any of my libraries around the time the errors started showing up.

**UPDATE:**
Marked as fixed again:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160907013#comment256

Comment: I got the same crash in Pre-launch report with device Nokia 1. I feel confused because it looks having nothing to do with Firebase-Messaging and youtube.

Comment: I'm getting it with every release now.

Comment: People over here have the same issue:
https://forums.expo.io/t/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle/45041/3

Comment: i'm getting the same problem with nokia 1, i'm using firebase-bom:26.0.0 & firebase-messaging-ktx and all configured with documentation of google, still working on it, but i think it's a google problem because in local devices physical or emulated this problem not shown

Comment: I only got this issue after I have enabled zipAlign, minify and shrinkResources in my flutter project. Never had this issue before. Maybe shrinking and minifying removes the class it wants to use? I only use firebase in my application, but no youtube or related.

Comment: i got the same error with Nokia 1 device when publishing updates too. I don't even use firebase messaging or youtube. And I did not change any dependencies. Maybe it is a problem with the test device? I am using firestore flutter and Cloud functions.

Comment: I've been using minify and shrinkresources for over a year in this project and only started getting the error on November 4 2020. No error on November 1st.

Comment: Yeah, that's very weird,I had 0 environment changes from my previous update, I suppose it is an error on google's test device,  are you going to open a support ticket with google? @grolschie

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start opening a support ticket for this particular issue. I'll see what happens with my upload with minify disabled first. It's taking forever to process. Maybe it'll reveal more info.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Nokia 1. But sometimes the Huawei P8 青春版 also.

Comment: Same thing here. Started getting this several days ago from Huawei P8 青春版. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Only 3 devices are being tested in Play Console - none are the problematic ones. So false alarm on being free of errors.

Comment: The same here, on Nokia 1 and Huawei P8 青春版.

Comment: I have an update that I need to roll out. I'm reluctant to do so, in case it's a problem with R8 or Android Studio 4.1, instead of with Pre-Launch reports.

Comment: Have you ads on your app?

Comment: No ads in my app.

Comment: Opened a support ticket on google dev console, linking this page too. Let's see what their answer, hoping it won't be a silly "AI" one.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, next-hack. Is it a public ticket?

Comment: Nope, I just used the support. I'll post here the solution. I can't answer to this question, as I don't have enough reputation here...

Comment: I have absolutely the same issue (H. P8 and N. 1) with my flutter App on Google Play. What I noticed - in my App I open a video on youtube (video tutorial), so the playback video shows "Youtube stopped working" error while launching. App itself starts and works stable. So, one can investigate deeper what causes Youtube issue on these devices.

Comment: Inside the "Pre-launch report overview" they advise to "Test your app on even more devices" by using "Firebase Test Lab". I did upload the same app bundle to Firebase and used "Nokia 1" for the test. I can confirm that it works without issues on Firebase but on Google Play this error gets reported. This is keeping me busy for hours now...

Comment: Now raised on the firebase-android-sdk GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2161)

Comment: Someone has also raised it here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/861

Comment: And here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2161#issuecomment-724968851

Comment: Can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909635/set-mutability-flag-for-pending-intent-but-still-receiving-illegalargumentexcept if facing `IllegalArgumentException` also along with this error.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Solution:** ignore

All signs point to this being a problem with Google Play's Pre-launch Reports and not our code.

**Edit:**
Google's product and engineering teams [are now aware](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160907013#comment25) of the issue. But it seems they might need a few more people to give them a sense of the scale of the issue. Perhaps consider posting on the bug report.

**Update:**
Google have fixed it now by adding a filter for the process. See [comment 256](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160907013#comment256) on the bug report.

I have uploaded a few versions of my app and the problem is now gone.

Comment: Thanks. but is it true that I cannot release my app as long as this problem persists ? (because Pre-launch report overview says "Errors found. Fix before releasing to production."

Comment: I have submitted an enquiry formally to Play Console support. Let's see what they will reply

Comment: Hi Ken. I had no problem rolling my app out to both Open Testing and also Production. I rolled it out to "99.999%" of my users, that way I can halt the release if I start seeing errors.

Comment: Thank you. I will try debugging/checking this problem by submitting a barebone App to the Play Console and then add more modules to see what module(s) are causing this problem.

Comment: Hello All, The result is : even if I submit a barebone APP (just a single page APP showing a few lines of text) and NO OTHER FUNCTIONS , it will have the FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle, Process: com.google.android.youtube, error in Huawei P8 . Hence it is for sure not code related. I hope that Google will fix the problem ASAP.

Comment: By the way Google still did not answer to my support ticket... Glad to know that this is just their fault.

Comment: Thanks for the update, next-hack. That's rather disappointing.

Answer (score 10):

I also have the same problem when trying to publish a new version of my application also developed in java with android studio, in the pre launch an error is shown for the Huawei P8 青春 版 device with Android 5.0 (SDK 21). The error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 27648
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
    at aewu.b(PG:1)
    at duc.a(PG:230)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at aevw.b(PG:1)
    at dud.al(PG:5)
    at dud.aw(PG:4)
    at dud.bg(PG:8)
    at duc.a(PG:232)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at afke.a(PG:1)
    at aeri.b(PG:1)
    at dud.fv(PG:4)
    at duc.c(PG:269)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at amfk.a(PG:1)
    at eiu.K(PG:5)
    at dud.fV(PG:7)
    at duc.d(PG:334)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
    at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at usj.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

But when downloading the full log I find that the error appears before the application starts:

```
11-08 06:57:29.438: E/AndroidRuntime(27648): FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
11-08 06:57:29.438: E/AndroidRuntime(27648): Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 27648
11-08 06:57:29.438: E/AndroidRuntime(27648): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
...
```

But in the video that google makes for the test the application never fails and you can clearly see that it starts at 06:57:07, so the times don't match.

```
1-08 06:59:07.758: W/PGApi_client(3556): recv actoionId = 10000, action = com.huawei.pgmng.PGAction@13714f2a actionId =10000 pkg =com.MYAPP.MYAPP extend1 =0 extend2 = flag =3 type =1
11-08 06:59:07.758: W/PGMiddleWare jhh(3556): in handleAction method, action = 10000
11-08 06:59:07.758: W/PGMiddleWare jhh(3556): in handleAction, invoke client = com.huawei.pgmng.middleware.AudioEffectLowPowerImpl@2725ca70, action = com.huawei.pgmng.PGAction@13714f2a actionId =10000 pkg =com.MYAPP.MYAPP extend1 =0 extend2 = flag =3 type =1
11-08 06:59:07.758: I/AudioEffectLowPowerImpl jhh(3556): jhh handle default mActionId = 10000, action = com.huawei.pgmng.PGAction@13714f2a actionId =10000 pkg =com.MYAPP.MYAPP extend1 =0 extend2 = flag =3 type =1
11-08 06:59:07.758: W/AudioEffectLowPowerImpl jhh(3556): enter into DEFAULT_FRONT Scene.
```

Check the registry in detail, if it is the same case we can only wait for google to fix the problem on their test devices or publish the application and that some user with that device has the same error.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was happening because I deleted a class, but forgot to remove a reference to it in AndroidManifest.xml.

Go through your AndroidManifest.xml and make sure it doesn't reference any non-existent classes, they will likely show as red, but surprisingly the project will still build.

The name is likely showing as aewt because of build minification / obfuscation. I have absolutely no idea why the error message references youtube, it does for me too when I don't use youtube in the app.

The crash log in the pre-release report was totally useless, but a crash log in firebase crashlytics revealed the source of the issue.

I'm still waiting for a pre-release report to undoubtedly confirm, which I'll have later today, but it seems highly likely based on the firebase crashlytics report and the circumstances.

Edit: My pre-release report is no longer showing this error and is totally passing after removing the hanging reference from the androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Are you writing a completely native kotlin/java application or using something cross-platform like flutter?

Comment: Completely native java app in android studio

Comment: Do you have any ideas what else could cause this issue as my andoirdManifest only contains a reference to my flutter mainActivtiy?

Comment: I've not used flutter before so the only two things I can think of are: do a search for any remaining references to any classes you've deleted recently, or if possible add firebase crashlytics to your app to get a better crash report.

Comment: Regarding "aewt", thanks. I will upload a version without minify (which my project has used for over 1 year). I checked my androidmanifest.xml, and the last change made was 1 months prior to the errors starting. No changes in gradle.build besides build version numbers. No classes deleted.

Comment: Interestingly, when uploading a version with minify disabled I see this warning: "This App Bundle contains Java/Kotlin code, which might be obfuscated. We recommend that you upload a deobfuscation file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug."

Comment: Only 3 devices are being tested in Play Console - none are the problematic ones. So false alarm on being free of errors.

Comment: Might this issue related to ads? Could they "silently" add some firebase/yt code/library ?

Comment: No ads in my app.

Comment: We also encounter this issue... It fails randomly.

Comment: There is also  the possibility, very likely as i have found it also randomly to me, that this error is NOT RELATED to your app at all, and it is an error with youtube app. Are you using any kind of video package in your flutter app that may use youtube somehow?

Comment: @next-hack Maybe? I've been getting the same error (on Huawei P8 and Nokia 1) on Google Play and the only explanation I can think of is video ads - maybe they play videos hosted on youtube. My app has a banner ad and I have allowed video ads - so this might explain it

Comment: For me also showing same error. In same devices. It in prelaunch because of this error. Alpha version is not publishing. How to ignore and publish the version alpha testing. The app is publishing for first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this problem is caused on specific devices (Nokia Nokia 1 and Huawei P8), the problems is a bug from Google pre-launch test lab, if this problems were this unique that showed to you, you just need ignore really, this problem appear more or less three months, Google will resolve it, we do not just know when...

Answer (score 0):

Removing Nokia 1 from supported device list should help

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not related to Firebase library because this problem occurs to many users who are not using Firebase library, after several days trying to understand this issue I think this issue is related to google play service app update method (app bundle). Why do I think the problem is in the google play service? because this problem occurs to users starting around 11/1/2020, I think on this date google update google play service and the problem starts from here, there is another reason for me, when I do some change in a certain place in my code and I republish the app in playstore the problem suddenly disappears and when I republish it the problem appears again. For all these reasons, I think the problem is in the google play service.

-Removing an unnecessary reference from the Manifest file temporarily fixes the problem, but if you try to republish your app, the problem reappears again!

Comment: Do you think that the new version of google services are using firebase for analytics or crash report, and it contain a bug that's caussing this issue ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio The problem is not in the firbase library but I think in the google play service itself, when it tries to replace the old application with the new one, somehow this operation does not happen correctly. It's just a guess I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the title and message was an empty string.

Answer (score -3):

I had this issue after updating to firebase latest SDK. The issue was, I hadn't remove the reference of a service which was previously removed from app.

- **check your manifest and remove unnecessary references** which will be shown by red color.

By doing that, I was able to remove this error from prelaunch report.

Comment: I get this error and I've never ever used Firebase.