# FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle Process: com.google.android.youtube on pre launch google play console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, prelaunch

I am uploading a new version of my application to the internal testing phase and I am seeing an error related to FirebaseMessagingService and Youtube, I do have an integration with FirebaseMessagingService but the implementations are up to date. The result of the automatic test that Google performed shows me the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 27648
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
    at aewu.b(PG:1)
    at duc.a(PG:230)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at aevw.b(PG:1)
    at dud.al(PG:5)
    at dud.aw(PG:4)
    at dud.bg(PG:8)
    at duc.a(PG:232)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at afke.a(PG:1)
    at aeri.b(PG:1)
    at dud.fv(PG:4)
    at duc.c(PG:269)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at amfk.a(PG:1)
    at eiu.K(PG:5)
    at dud.fV(PG:7)
    at duc.d(PG:334)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
    at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at usj.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

On my build.gradle (Module: App) i have the following:

```
    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.1'
```

And i am implementing everything according to the documentation

Comment: I think it may be just a problem with the test device, im seeing the log and the time when the error happens doesnt match with the time when the app start to run. The error is shown in 11-08 06:57:29.438 but the app doesnt start until 11-08 06:59:08

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem on google devices, the solution is to wait for them to fix it. For more information see the following question:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder/64744616#64744616)