# FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle — com.google.android.youtube — lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, prelaunch

I'm faced with almost the same problem [FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder/64740100#64740100). I was trying to update for the latest version of firebase analytics and messaging, and in one build it`s work for me. But after I removed some SDK(Facebook and Tenjin), and upload a new build this error show again. I try to remove all firebase, but the error still here, even when I don't use firebase.

On closed testing I am seeing crashes with this:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt

FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle

Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 28501

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt

```
at aewu.b(PG:1)
at duc.a(PG:230)
at duc.get(PG:247)
at aevw.b(PG:1)
at dud.al(PG:5)
at dud.aw(PG:4)
at dud.bg(PG:8)
at duc.a(PG:232)
at duc.get(PG:247)
at afke.a(PG:1)
at aeri.b(PG:1)
at dud.fv(PG:4)
at duc.c(PG:269)
at duc.get(PG:247)
at amfk.a(PG:1)
at eiu.K(PG:5)
at dud.fV(PG:7)
at duc.d(PG:334)
at duc.get(PG:247)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at usj.run(PG:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

on Huawei P8 青春版 and Nokia Nokia 1 devices.

If someone knows how to fix that error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder)

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been reported.
For more details about it check the actual issue ticket in the firebase repository:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2161

At the time of this answer there is no solution yet, so it would be better to keep a watch on the repository issue thread.