# I have got this FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle play store console?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play-console

I have in trouble unable to resolve it, this error occurs on play console in Pre-launch report, I have enable push notification in my app. I have used lib [firebase_in_app_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages?q=firebase_in_app_messaging) in flutter and also use analytics [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics)

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
Process: com.google.android.youtube, PID: 28593
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
    at aewu.b(PG:1)
    at duc.a(PG:230)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at aevw.b(PG:1)
    at dud.al(PG:5)
    at dud.aw(PG:4)
    at dud.bg(PG:8)
    at duc.a(PG:232)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at afke.a(PG:1)
    at aeri.b(PG:1)
    at dud.fv(PG:4)
    at duc.c(PG:269)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at amfk.a(PG:1)
    at eiu.K(PG:5)
    at dud.fV(PG:7)
    at duc.d(PG:334)
    at duc.get(PG:247)
    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.common.notification.FcmMessageListenerService.b(PG:1)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.g(PG:53)
    at avgp.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at usj.run(PG:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

[image: Device Info]

I have added device info screenshot error occurs on only that device.
Anyone can resolve this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to firebase, you are on the right track, but you will probably need to disable minify and shrink in order to see the actual guilty class - the actual class is not named "aewt". In your build.gradle add the following lines to buildTypes\release:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
```

Rebuild and the real culprid should present itself :)  Next, to solve this, you will probably need to fix your AndroidManifest.xml - probably you have there a reference to a class that no longer exists, also probably related to an upgrade to a Firebase component.

Comment: sorry for late, that is not work