# android pre-launch-report - java.lang.RuntimeException with com.google.android.finsky.services.IMarketCatalogService

Tags: java, android

I have received a pre-launch report on my play.google.com/console:

```
Android 8.1 (SDK 27)
FATAL EXCEPTION: UIAsyncWorker
Process: com.google.android.music:main, PID: 11466
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.services.IMarketCatalogService.isBackendEnabled(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.CallerTracker.reThrowExceptionWithCallerStackTrack(CallerTracker.java:32)
    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.TraceableRunnable.runLogged(TraceableRunnable.java:23)
    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.LoggedRunnable.run(LoggedRunnable.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.google.android.music.utils.LoggableHandler.dispatchMessage(LoggableHandler.java:74)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.services.IMarketCatalogService.isBackendEnabled(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.checkStoreAvailable(SignupStatus.java:216)
    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.doCheck(SignupStatus.java:154)
    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.launchVerificationCheck(SignupStatus.java:129)
    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.launchVerificationCheckWithFallbackTask(SignupStatus.java:113)
    at com.google.android.music.AccountsBroadcastReceiver$1.run(AccountsBroadcastReceiver.java:30)
    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.TraceableRunnable.runLogged(TraceableRunnable.java:21)
    ... 6 more
```

com.google.android.music - is not my application.

Can I fix the issue or it is a problem in the android device and not in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this now, in addition to another [similar bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706041/fatal-exception-firebase-messaging-intent-handle-java-lang-noclassdeffounder/64839467) affecting a lot of users. It appears to be yet another bug in the Pre-launch reports and not related to our code. My app doesn't use sound, let alone Android Music.

Those affected, please consider reporting it on this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160907013).