# Set mutability flag for pending intent but still receiving IllegalArgumentException error

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, android-service, android-pendingintent

I am facing an issue with firebase cloud messaging notifications for Android 12. I previously faced `Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.` and then set the mutability flag accordingly. After setting the flag, I still receive the same error when my app is in the background. Here is my code -

```
    private void sendDishReadyNotification(String title, String description) {


        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.bigText(description);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                    (this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                    (this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Kitchen Display";


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .build();

            Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alert);

            //Configure Notification Channel
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Kitchen Display Notifications");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setStyle(style)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                //.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);


        notificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
        AppData.isNotificationClicked = true;
    }
```

The error I keep receiving even after setting mutability flags -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.quicklyservices.restaurants, PID: 6690
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.quicklyservices.restaurants: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createContentIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:125)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:27)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:9)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.DisplayNotification.handleNotification(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:27)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:55)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:34)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:27)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:17)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:43)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrade your dependency

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
```

Comment: or 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'.
Yeah, it helped

Comment: It worked @s01, here is a link where we can find the latest version https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

write this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_MUTABLE | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my dependency as suggested by the answer above I was still receiving the error. Apparently, this is a bug in the work manager library. Updating the work manager version to 2.7.0-alpha05 or 2.7.1

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
```

For kotlin -

```
 implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
```

Note,you still have to set the mutability flags.